# How do you manage you assets?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, uwp, assets

Especially when dealing with a Xamarin.Forms solution, you have to cope with icons, images, vectorfonts, etc. pp. for different devices in different resolutions and sizes including all store-prerequisites in regards to icons, banners and such.

How do you manage all of these in a suitable way? Is there something like a best practice you can recommend or even a software product that helps (maybe even by offering automatic rescaling of high-res images to specific device needs)?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question

Answer (score 1):

The main and best apps used by designers and developers are vector-based and allow you to export assets for all required resolutions.

There are a lot of great tutorials online on how to export assets for iOS, Android, App Store and Google Play.

- [Sketch](https://www.sketch.com/)
- [Adobe XD](https://www.adobe.com/products/xd.html) (free)
- [Figma](https://www.figma.com/) (has a free plan)